# Tables.Select on Unicode Characters

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Select("name = '" + _string + "'");
```

If _string contains **UNICODE** characters, do I need to prefix it with N like in TSQL?

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Select("name = N'" + _string + "'");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it. Adding an N-Prefix will throw an exception.

You don't need to put the N-Prefix even if you are working with Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

DataRow[] rows = myDatatable.Select("name = '" + _string + "'");

_string includes Myanmar Unicode string and wrong result returns(i.e. it returned all strings that include Myanmar Characters).
What's wrong with me?

I also tried 
myDatatable.DefaultView.RowFilter("name = '" + _string + "'");
the same wrong result return.